# Python Client Server Query execution

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, subprocess

I have a client server program. Client daemon is running on multiple host via root login. In client program I have used “subprocess .Popen” to execute a command. I want to write the o/p,error of this command to a file shared over NFS via the user login who submitted the job.

But as client is running via root so it tried to write the file file root login and throwing permission denied error.

Below is the code:

```
def demote(self,user_uid, user_gid):
    def result():

        os.setgid(user_gid)
        os.setuid(user_uid)

    return result

def log_file(self,myList = [], *args):
    try:
        with open(myList[-1], 'a+') as file:
            fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
            file.write(myList[0])
            fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
    except IOError as e:
        print('err in file locking')

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=self.demote(user_uid, user_gid),stderr=subprocess.PIPE,env=my_env)
output,error = proc.communicate()
output = output.decode("utf-8")
error = error.decode("utf-8")
print("Here is the O/p")
print(output)
print("Here is the error")
print(error)
exit_code = proc.returncode
logfile="/home/user/abd"
if output:
    print("I have some O/P")
    print(output)
    self.log_file([output,logfile])
if error:
    print("I have some error")
    print(error)
    self.log_file([error,logfile])

self.conn.send(repr(exit_code).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: any help will be much appreciated.